# How can I properly fix this ruby file output?

Tags: ruby

Using this code format:

```
class Country
  CODE_TO_NAME = {
    :us => 'United States',
    :mx => 'Mexico',
    :fr => 'France',
    :gr => 'Germany'
  }

  def self.name(code)
    # Write some code here
  end
end

puts Country.name(ARGV.shift)
```

I want my code to run with output like this:

```
$ ruby country_name.rb
Code not specified
$ ruby country_name.rb ca
Not match
$ ruby country_name.rb us
United States
$ ruby country_name.rb mx
Mexico
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: We do not provide exam/interview solutions here, better you try and post your problem, Answer will provided just to describe their intelligence & achieve improvement, but not for your direct help

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure I understand. I'm quite new to stack overflow.

Comment: FYI, "Not match" is sort of broken English. (Not sure if it is typical of Japanese Engrish.) It should be either "Does not match" or "No match". But I hope you do not change the question since you already got answers.

Answer (score 1):

So, there are three cases we need to care about:

1. the user supplies no code
2. the user supplies a code that is not in the database
3. the user supplies a code that is in the database

In the first case, `ARGV.first` will be `nil`. We can add a `nil` key to `CODE_TO_NAME` with the appropriate message.

In the second case, indexing into `CODE_TO_NAME` will return the default value, so we can set the default to the appropriate message.

In the third case, the code we get from the command line will be a `String`, not a `Symbol`, so if we change the keys in `CODE_TO_NAME` to `String`s, we can index into `CODE_TO_NAME` directly without any conversions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Country
  CODE_TO_NAME = Hash.new('Not match').merge({
    'us' => 'United States',
    'mx' => 'Mexico',
    'fr' => 'France',
    'gr' => 'Germany', # BTW, the ISO-3166-1 alpha-2 code for Germany is 'de'
    nil  => 'Code not specified'
  }).freeze

  def self.name(code)
    CODE_TO_NAME[code]
  end
end

puts Country.name(ARGV.shift)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, name your code's path as `country_name.rb`. Then, define `Country.name` as:

```
def self.name(code)
  case
  when code.nil? then "Code not specified"
  when name = CODE_TO_NAME[code.to_sym] then name
  else "Not match"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option, checking for the code before calling the method:

```
class Country
  # no changes here

  def self.name(code)
    return "Not found" unless CODE_TO_NAME.has_key? code
    CODE_TO_NAME[code]
  end
end

code = ARGV[0]
abort("Code not specified") unless code
puts Country.name(code.to_sym)
```

Comment: It's not "Code not provided", but is "Code not specified".